# Elasticsearch query to return documents with given ids

Tags: node.js, http, elasticsearch, dsl

All the documents in the elasticsearch index have an `id` field.

I have an array of `id`s and I want to fetch documents with `id`s in this array. What is the elasticsearch query for this task?

Answer (score 2):

let's say you have ids in array like `["36088175", "36088176"]`

The query will be

```
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "_id" : ["36088175", "36088176"]
        }
    }
}
```

see terms query for more details - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Answer (score 1):

Saga, the most efficient query for this is an `mget` :

Example :

```
GET myindex/_mget
{
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_id" : "fIjOTW8BkTKnAOE5HVit"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "fojOTW8BkTKnAOE5UliD"
        }
    ]
}
```

More information on [Elasticsearch's documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-get.html)