# How to index data from lambda to aws elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Am trying to index some data using AWS lambda into AWS-elasticsearch
I install `"aws-elasticsearch-js": "^1.0.3"` and granted required permissions on AWS, my ES version is `Elasticsearch 7.10` and am trying to run  a basic example like below

```
const elasticsearch = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const { createConnector } = require('aws-elasticsearch-js');

const region = process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-east-1';
const domain = 'my-index.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/';

const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    nodes: [domain],
    Connection: createConnector({ region })
});

async function example() {

    let result = await client.search({ index: 'kibana_sample_data_ecommerce' });
    return result
}

module.exports = {
    example
}
```

but am getting this error in the logs and am not sure how to fix it

`"Cannot read property 'x-elastic-product' of undefined"`

**UPDATE**

I've deleted, reinstalled `node_modules` but now am getting a new error message `"The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch"`

Comment: I had to downgrade the elasticsearch version as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617066/elasticsearch-query-to-return-documents-with-given-ids)

Comment: it will be depends on which version of Elasticsearch / Opensearch (AWS changed ES service name to opensearch) you are using.  It should be same as your ES version.